# Fatal error in: ../../src/modules/utility/source/helpers_android.cc, line 74

Tags: android, webrtc, opentok, webrtc-android

We are facing one issue related to Opentokfor Android and we have added proguard in it. You can have a look at log-cat for crash logs.

Logcat crash logs -

````
    # last system error: 2
    # Check failed: !jni->ExceptionCheck()
    # Error during FindClass: org/otwebrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo```
````

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding these lines in Proguard

````
-keep class com.opentok.android.Session { *; }
-keep class com.opentok.client.* { *; }
-keep class com.opentok.impl.* { *; }
-keep class com.opentok.otc.* { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.* { *; }
-keep class org.otwebrtc.* { *; }
-keep class org.otwebrtc.voiceengine.* { *; }
-keep class org.otwebrtc.voiceengine.*
-keep class org.otwebrtc.WebRtcClassLoader{*;}
-keep class org.otwebrtc.voiceengine61.* { *; }
-keep class org.otwebrtc.voiceengine.BuildInfo { *; }

-dontwarn com.opentok.*
-keepclassmembers class com.opentok.* { *; }```
````